# KeyListener as sub-class of an Object does not work

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, subclass, keylistener

Basically what i am trying to do is , i have an object , which is called mainball. Mainball has an keydetecter class as its innerclass, the keydetecter is added to mainball on the constructor. Mainball is created in the game but mainball does not respond to keystrikes.

```
public Mainball(){
    super(150,150,SIZE,SIZE);
    c=  Color.RED;
    addKeyListener(new KeyDetecter());
}
class KeyDetecter extends KeyAdapter{

    public KeyDetecter(){
    }

    double velocityfactor = 0.8;

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'a'){
            x_velocity = -velocityfactor;
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'd'){
            x_velocity = velocityfactor;
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 's'){
            ball.y_velocity = velocityfactor;
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'w'){
            y_velocity = -velocityfactor;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == '1'){
            Shoot_Type = the_Game.SHOOT_ARROW;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == '2'){
            Shoot_Type = the_Game.SHOOT_PARTICLE;
        }
    }
```

the Game requests focus on window here aswell

```
if(button.getText().equals("Game")){
            try {
                game.walls = (ArrayList<wall>) SaveNLoad.load("wall_info.txt");
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                game.walls = new ArrayList<wall>();
            }
            frame.remove(current_panel);
            frame.add(game);
            game.ball.requestFocusInWindow(); /* ball is an mainball instance */
            current_panel = game;
            game.ball.x_center = 100;
            game.ball.y_center = 40;
            game.ball.y_velocity = 0;
        }
```

Comment: A bit of vocabulary pedantery: "KeyDetecter" isn't a subclass (which would extend Mainball), it's an inner class, with its enclosing type being Mainball.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `KeyEvent` the [`getKeyChar()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#setKeyChar(char)) method states:

> KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED events are not intended for reporting of character input. Therefore, the values returned by this method are guaranteed to be meaningful only for KEY_TYPED events.

So in the above example I think it would be better if you put the entire code for key handling in `KeyAdapter's keyTyped(KeyEvent e)` method.

Comment: It unfortunantly does not chance anything

Comment: @Eren did you debug the program?

Comment: I dont know how to use debugger, but i did add an system.out.print under keyTyped and it didnt work

Comment: That means the the registered `KeyEvent` is not firing. But tell me what is the super of  `MainBall` class?

Comment: Its another object that extends JPanel , that object only stores simple data such as x_center,y_center,x_size,y_size

Comment: @Eren have you used a code to get focus to the `MainBall` object in your program?

Comment: yes, its in the second code field , game.ball.requestFocusInWindow();

Comment: @Eren Why didn't you write the code as `addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){//the remaining part of code});`?

Comment: what am i supposed to write after new KeyDetecter part? , KeyDetecter is already defined on its own class

Comment: @Eren I am asking you why have you not written it that way is there any special reason? If not give it a try

Comment: There is no special reason, i did not know i could write it like that. The problem is, when i use same detecter but add the detecter to the game, it works perfectly fine, when i add the detecter to ball and request focus to ball , it does not work at all

Comment: @Eren Are you sure that the `ball` is gaining focus? In other words is the `ball` focusable?

Comment: I would suggest you do some serious debugging.

Comment: I gave up in my idea of implementing keylistener to mainball, i will use it on  the_game instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tested it for you and this works perfectly fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame t = new JFrame();
        t.setSize(500, 500);
        t.addKeyListener(new KL());
        t.setVisible(true);
    }

public static class KL extends KeyAdapter{

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'a') System.out.println("a pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are direclty adding listener to listener to frame, that is not what im doing. Im adding listener to an object, which is added to a JPanel , which is added to JFrame

Comment: @Eren Where is the method `addKeyListener`? And what do you call with `super` in Mainball?

Comment: addKeyListener is in the 4th line of the code , i call Virtual_Object with super method, which is another object that only stores basic attributes such as x_center, y_center

Comment: @Eren Post all relevant classes pls.

Comment: public abstract class Virtual_Object extends JPanel implements Serializable{double x_center;
 double y_center;
 int x_size;
 int y_size;

Comment: there is no other relevant class then the one i just wrote

Comment: @Eren The KeyAdapter only works if you have _focus_ on the component. If it's in a `JFrame` you have focus on the JFrame and not the JPanel.

Comment: component already requests focus in 2nd line of code, game.ball.requestFocusInWindow();  i tried requesting focus on game and the frame itself, it chanced nothing